# R quantile equal sized bucket after summarizing to the buckets

Tags: r

How do I make the quantity such that each group will be equal size after summing?

Below is an example that divides quantity into 10 groups with the same number of items per group.

```
    set.seed(42)
    quantity <- c(runif(100, 0, 100))
    dat <- data.frame(
      qty = quantity,
      qtile = cut(quantity, quantile(quantity, seq(0, 1, 0.1)), 
      include.lowest = TRUE))
    dat <- dat %>% group_by(qtile) %>% summarise(qty = sum(qty))
    ggplot(dat, aes(qtile, qty)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

But how do I sort the groups such that at the `summarise` step the `qty` variable will be roughly equal by group?

So in this example, the total `qty` is `5244.787`, each group will have `524.4787` after `summarise`.

Comment: `dplyr` has a `cut_number` function. From the docs: "`cut_number` makes n groups with (approximately) equal numbers of observations"

Comment: @camille, I am not looking for equal number of observations by group. I am looking for roughly equal sum by group. See my answer for an example. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

This is as far as I could get to. I feel it works approximately for my use case. If anyone else has good ideas for improvement feel free to update the answer.

```
set.seed(42)
quantity <- c(runif(100, 0, 100))

dat <- data.table(
  qty = quantity,
  wt = quantity
)
dat[!is.na(qty), avg := sum(wt) / 10]
setorder(dat, qty, wt)
dat[!is.na(qty), cum_wt := cumsum(wt)]
dat[!is.na(qty), level := cum_wt / avg]
dat[!is.na(qty), qtile := ceiling(level)]

dat <- dat[, .(qty = sum(qty)), by = 'qtile']

ggplot(dat, aes(qtile, qty)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```